# I cannot connect internet through micromax 300g usb modem with BSNL data card on ubuntu 10.10.It doesn't even identify modem attached.What to do?

Tags: internet

The details of the problem have been given in the question itself.I installed ubuntu 10.10 alongside windows 7 and wanna work internet on it but network applet doesn't show any connection.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of connecting micromax UsbModem for Internet Access -
Micromax USBModem have not any installation software for LINUX Operating System so you have to configure it yourself for getting access of Internet.
Sakis3G only works with GSM networks. Connecting with aCDMA network is not yet possible.
Your Micromax USBModem can be -

```
Micromax on BSNL3g
Micromax on AIRCEL
Micromax on CHROME etc.
```

you all have the same problem of not detecting or not connecting to Internet.

NOW for configuration of your Micromax USBModem, go through some steps as -

1. Download Sakis-3g from Sakis-3g website  ( download as per your system requirements )
2. Extract it to home folder  ( download in any system as in your windows OS and extract it , then copy & paste in home folder in Linux )
3. Open Terminal in Linux ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> )
4. Enter : `$ sudo chmod +x sakis3g`
5. Enter : `$ sudo .//sakis3g helper balloons`
6. Now connect Micromax usb modem to your laptop and wait for a while.
7. Now sakis3g is working and a popup message will be showing detection of your modem ( if popped up message is not coming then you have not download proper sakis3g as you need ).
8. Click the icon & it will brought up a menu driven tool.
9. Make a shortcut on clicking CREATE SHORTCUT in your Desktop.
10. Now click on Connect with 3G & go as per your connection ( as airtel,bsnl,reliance or whatever ... ).

for more check it : http://ashishkumar1991.blogspot.in/2013/01/micromax-usbmodem-installation-in-linux.html

Sakis3g :

The sakis-3g.org website has been down for some time. Fortunately somebody has uploaded a copy of the script to sourceforge. To download go to link :
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/vim-n4n0/sakis3g.tar.gz

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.